# sql, selecting using condition from another table

Tags: sql

I have four tables,

```
game(game_id, game_name, date_of_release), 
category(game_id, game_category), 
company(company_id, company_name),
belongs_to(game_id, company_id)
```

I need to select game_id, game_name, and game_language where the company is 'Konami', I tried to do it like this

```
SELECT a.game_id, a.game_name, b.game_category, FROM game a 
    INNER JOIN category b ON a.game_id = b.game_id
    INNER JOIN company c ON  company_name = 'Konami' 
    INNER JOIN belongs_to d ON c.company_id = d.company_id
```

but it's selecting all the games regardless of the company name.
So what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join is wrong.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    game a
    INNER JOIN category b ON b.game_id = a.game_id
    INNER JOIN belongs_to d ON d.game_id = a.game_id
    INNER JOIN company c ON c.company_id = d.company_id
WHERE
    c.company_name = 'Konami'
```

Comment: Notice that in this query, belongs_to has been constrained by the value of a.game_id, and that company has been been constrained by the value of belongs_to's company_id.
In your query, you were basically unioning the game and category tables with the company table - which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you not really understand joins. You should use them to connect tables, in you case

```
INNER JOIN company c ON company_name = 'Konami'
```

You connected row with info about Konami to all rows in previous tables. Try to think only about how you connect tables, not how you filter it while writing join clause

So, you can fix it like this: just add condition that shows how to connect tables

```
SELECT a.game_id, a.game_name, b.game_category
FROM game a 
INNER JOIN category b ON a.game_id = b.game_id
INNER JOIN belongs_to d ON a.game_id = d.game_id 
INNER JOIN company c ON  c.company_id = d.company_id
WHERE company_name = 'Konami'
```

It's better to filter in where clause, but this will work fine too

```
SELECT a.game_id, a.game_name, b.game_category
FROM game a 
INNER JOIN category b ON a.game_id = b.game_id
INNER JOIN belongs_to d ON a.game_id = d.game_id 
INNER JOIN company c ON c.company_id = d.company_id
                     AND company_name = 'Konami'
```